# How to calculate correlation matrix between binary variables in r?

Tags: r, correlation

I have dataframe of 10 binary variables, looked like this:

```
V1 V2 V3...
0  1  1
1  1  0
1  0  1
0  0  1
```

I need to get the correlation matrix then I can do factor analysis.
`psych::corr.test` can calculate calculate the correlation matrix,but has only `person`,`spearman`,`kendall` methods,not used for binary data.
Then, how to calculate the correlation matrix of this dataframe?

Comment: Actually, you can use the Pearson correlation coefficient also for binary variables. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient

Comment: Instead of calculating correlation, I would rather use similarity coefficients/metrics like Jaccard.

Comment: also depends what your variables represent. If they could be indicators of an underlying normally distributed variable you could use tetrachoric correlations.

Comment: Is tetrachoric correlation a kind of  person correlation coefficient? I only know person,spearman,kendall correlation coefficient.

Comment: @WhiteGirl ; no it is a different correlation measure. Say for example, one binary variable is feeling guilt, measured as yes / no. Is it truly dichotomous - probably not as you reasonably assume further ordered categories eg as very guilty, a little guilty, not at al lguilty. In fact it may be reasonable to think there is a latent/underlying continuous factor that is indicated by your measured yes/no variable. This factor is assumed normally distributed in tetrachoric correlation calculations

Comment: maybe of interest https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3086/differences-between-tetrachoric-and-pearson-correlation

Comment: @user20650,check the `psych::tetrachoric` help file,`The tetrachoric correlation is the inferred Pearson Correlation from a two x two table with the assumption of bivariate normality. The polychoric correlation generalizes this to the n x m table. `. In your answer, the guilt variable cannot use tetrachoric function, because options number >2.

Comment: my comment was trying to illustrate that dichotomous variable guilty was ordered, that it could reasonably have been recorded in > 2 states, and further could be generated by an underlying continuous variable. I was trying to be helpful as I didnt want to just jump from 2 states to continuous, but I see my language was confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# create data
m <- matrix(sample(x = 0:1,size = 200,replace = T),ncol = 10)
colnames(m) <- LETTERS[1:10]
m
# create cor matrix
res <- data.frame()
for(i in seq(ncol(m))){
  z <- m[,i]
  z <- apply(m,2,function(x){sum(x==z)/length(z)})
  res <- rbind(res,z)
}
colnames(res) <- colnames(m)
rownames(res) <- colnames(m)
res <- as.matrix(res)
res
```

Comment: So this calculates the proportion in agreement? (`all.equal((crossprod(m) + crossprod(!m))/ nrow(m) , res)`)

Comment: I'm more inclined to the term accuracy , but I guess it can be called like this

Answer (score 0):

Correl methods are suitable for continuous data. https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-calculate-correlations-between-binary-variables

Can u you try non parametric methods try http://www.cedar.buffalo.edu/papers/articles/CVPRIP03_propbina.pdf

You can still achieve factor analysis, calculate % match and remove variable matching >x%. This way you can remove the dimension of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hierarchical clustering on columns

> hclus(x)

or even better you can choose a clustering method from "ward.D", "ward.D2", "single", "complete"...
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/hclust

Another solution will be to visualize your binary matrix as a heatmap, a similar variable with common features